# Best way to run Regular Expression search on full MySQL Table?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, search

I'm trying to find users that have setup more than one free account on my website. I need to search a table full of URLs using regex to find a certain ID within those URLs, then compare it to the users table.

**For example, a row from the Users table looks like this:**

USERID = 1
ACCTYPE = 0
UNAME = John

**In the URLs table, the user stores a list of affiliate links.**

USERID = 1
URL = http:// example.com/?affid=1234

USERID = 1
URL = http:// example.com/cat3/?affid=1234

USERID = 2
URL = http:// example.com/cat3/?affid=5678

USERID = 3
URL = http:// example.com/cat6/?affid=1234

Added spaces to urls for demo only.

**I need to find any URLs with the same affid but different UserID.**

As you can see in the example above, USERID 3 has the same affid as USER1.

I'm not expecting anyone to write code for this, since I haven't provided a specific enough example. If someone could just explain the *theory* of how to do this, it would be very helpful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: why not make a new column and use a regex to capture that id out of the url just before you insert it

Comment: Best way would be **not to run** Regular Expression search on full MySQL Table Ever

Answer (score 1):

You could probably do a JOIN with the same table, but to make it efficient I would extract the affiliate id out of the URL at insert time, into its own column. 
That way your query would not require regular expression (LIKE) at all.